# Change a column in a DataTable where string equal a number

Tags: c#, datatable

In a DataTable I have a string column Salenumber.
I want to remove numbers between if they are between 1 - 100 and set it to "".

I cant use a IF statement like this, but this is what I want to do.

```
if (row["Salenumber"].ToString() >= 1 && row["Salenumber"].ToString() <= 100) 
    row.SetField("Salenumber", "");
```

I cant change the column to int. Maybe if there is a way to change it to int remove 1 - 100 then change it back.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: You are comparing string with integer. Your code does not _even_ compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
double RowDoubleValue;
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable) 
{
    if(Double.TryParse(row["Salenumber"].ToString(), out RowDoubleValue) && RowDoubleValue >= 1.0 && RowDoubleValue <= 100.0) 
    {
      row["Salenumber"] = "";
    }
}
```

Another option is to encapsupate the condition into a method as [Boas Enkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593461/boas-enkler) suggested in the comments:

```
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable) 
{
    if(IsANumberWithinRange(row["Salenumber"].ToString(), 1.0, 100.0)) 
    {
      row["Salenumber"] = "";
    }
}

private bool IsANumberWithinRange(string InputString, double MinValue, double MaxValue) 
{
    double Value;
    return (Double.TryParse(InputString, out RowIntValue) && RowIntValue >= MinValue && RowIntValue <= MaxValue)
}
```

**Note:** I've changed from int to double since this is a string column and it might contain any type of number.

Comment: Besides I would also recommend to encapsulate the comparison code in a method and call it . So it would look like   if(IsANumnder(row))

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the column to int, just cast the cell value to int to use in if statement

```
if (int.Parse(row["Salenumber"].ToString()) >= 1 && int.Parse(row["Salenumber"].ToString()) <= 100) 
       row.SetField("Salenumber", "");
```

Comment: What if the cell contains a non numeric value? And why parse twice?

Comment: The Salenumber seems to be a numeric values. If there is any chance then it could be handled using Int.TryParse and exception handling.

Comment: as posted above i think it would be more clear if its in a seperate method. but this is more related to codestyle then the quesion itself